# does location manager keeps working when device goes to sleep?

Tags: android, sleep, locationmanager, wakelock

My application requests for updates in a service on background when a boolean flag is set to true. If flag is set to true, then i acquire a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` to let my background service run.
  My questions are:

- Since I requested for updates from location manager ( i don't manually request updates but subscribed for `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` )... does the locationManager keep working as normal/usual even if device goes to sleep with `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` ?
- I've read there is a `WifiLock -> WIFI_MODE_SCAN_ONLY` that I'm not acquiring. Since location manager uses wifi scans to detect location through wifi hotspots, should I acquire this as well ?
- What about gps location updates when device goes to sleep ?

Answer (score 5):

1. no, it does not. More (very good) info [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10931), including possible solutions/ hacks.
2. regarding 1, I would have to make an educated guess and say it wouldn't make a difference
3. from what I can gather, it doesn't make a difference which provider you are using for the updates, `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` or `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`.

in danger of going a bit OQ, I am a bit curious which kind of application would need to aquire a wake lock to keep a service running at all. As far as I know, having a wake lock doesn't ensure your `Service` keeps running. The only thing which ensures a `Service` keeps running is to have it in the foreground ([`Service.startForeground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)). Otherwise the system still might kill the service, regardless if it aquired a wake lock or not.
That being said, if it is running, it can do it's work with a `Handler` or something.

If you are using this approach, and I think you are based on the scenario, I would advise against it. Basically you are creating a service, have it run in the foreground (guess) AND you are aquiring a wake lock just to request for location updates when the screen is off. This seems a bit overkill.

There's a more efficient way, which has the benefit it has by far more accurate timing then the dreaded timing of `Handler.postAtTime` or `Handler.postDelayed`: [`AlarmManager.setRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). Set type to ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP so it will run if the device sleeps, then when the alarm event is fired and received by a `BroadcastReceiver` you will have to create, you could request for updates and handle other events.

If you're not using a `Handler`, but are merely requesting location updates, this approach still probably would be better, because it doesn't require you to have a running `Service` or to acquire a wake lock.

And it seems [`LocationManager.addProximityAlert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) is the way to go here. Which is flawed as well (see 1)

Similar question here by the way: [Android: GPS location updates when the cellphone is in sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010011/android-gps-location-updates-when-the-cellphone-is-in-sleep?rq=1)

Comment: In the link you provided at the end of your post, the guy indicates that the screen "must" be on to get a GPS location. You didn't mention that. Is that true?

Comment: I think I did. See 1. When the device is in sleep, the screen is off. If the screen is on, the device normally isn't in sleep mode. As far as I know :)

Answer (score 0):

I've spent days trying to get WiFi and cell-based locations with locked screen with Android 6.0 on Nexus 6. And looks like the native android location service simple does not allow to do it. Once device got locked it still collects location update events for 10-15 minutes then stops to providing any of location updates.

In my case the solution was to switch from native Android location service to Google Play Services wrapper called com.google.android.gms.location: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary

Yes, I know that some of Android devices lack of GMS, but for my application this is the only solution to perform.

It does not stop sending location updates even when in the background and device screen is locked.

Me personally prefer RxJava library to wrap this service into a stream (examples included): https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation